# Entire function assume real values for $z=x^2+ix$

Tags: complex-analysis, conic-sections

Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(z)$ is real for $z=x^2+ix$.
Is there exists such a function which is not constant?

Previously I thought that  $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{z}\left(\sqrt{t-1/4}-i\right) dt \ $ would work but I realized that this function isn't continous so I cannot guarantee that this integral is entire.

Comment: I think that is not hard to prove the existence. I saw that a entire function always have a series expansion $\sum{a_nx^n}$ with radius infinity. Using the bionomial expansion for $z^n=x^n(x+i)^n$ and then observing that the imaginary part of the power series will be the odd powers of x we can find the coefficients by a linear system (the system will be indetermined). Now I am interested in find an explicit function.
Plus, I want to prove that $f'(-3/4)=0$. I tried a lot of things like an inversion with radius $1/2$ and center $1/4$, conformal mapping but I didn't manage to solve this problem.

Comment: Actually, will be a linear recurrence.

Comment: Did you show that the sequence of coefficients satisfies $\liminf_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n} = 0$, that is, the series has infinite radius of convergence?  Or maybe that added condition completely determines the coefficients?

Comment: This is a good point which I didn't care about before because I thought that is more important find a explicit function that satisfies the statment of the problem. But the coefficients of the linear recurrence are ${n \choose k}$ for $k>=(n-1)/2$ so I think that won't be hard to show that the radius is infinity for these coefficients.

Comment: I found that $\cos(2\pi\sqrt{1/4-z})$ satisfies the condition

Comment: That is very nice!  If you make it into an answer I will upvote it.  It took me long enough to check it.  How did you come up with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to reach at this answer I saw some facts:

1)$\cos(\sqrt{z})$ is an entire function - we can see this intuitively by the fact that cosine is even and with this we avoid the problem to define square root in $(-\infty,0]$ - which is a question here on Stack Exchange

2) $\cos2 \pi ix=\cosh2 \pi x$

So, to conclude I used what I think that was expected to be used, $x^2 +ix-1/4=(x+i/2)^2$

$f(z)=\cos2 \pi \sqrt{1/4-z}$ is a entire function and for $w=x^2 +ix$ we have
$f(w)=\cos2 \pi \sqrt{-(x+i/2)^2}=\cos2 \pi i(x+i/2)=\cos(2 \pi ix -\pi)=-\cos2 \pi ix=-\cosh2\pi x$ which is a real number for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score -1):

First we notice that the area above the given parabola is mapped eithe to the lower half plane or the upper half plane. Using conformal mapping we see that f(g) takes the upper half plane to itself with boundary to boundary. This needs not be constant for example z^3.

Comment: But if $z=x^2+ix$ then $z^3=x^6+3ix^5-3x^4-ix^3$ and this isn't real for every $x$ real.

Comment: No polynomial will work, because by considering $1/f(1/z)$ you can see that the set of points where $f(z)$ is real is going to be asymptotic to lines which are separated by the angle $2\pi/n$, where $n$ is the degree of $f$.